# Calling darknet API from python using ctypes (image as argument)

Tags: python, c, ctypes, darknet

I want to pass an image from python to C using ctypes.

I'm working with AlexeyAB's implementation of the darknet API: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet and I want to capture the image (potentially doing more processing) in python and perform prediction in C.

I have compiled as a shared library ("LIBSO=1" in the makefile).
The idea is to have two custom functions in the "detector.c" script. The first one initializes the network and saves it as a global variable (works so far) and the second function takes an image and predicts using this network.

I can't seem to figure out how to pass the image form python to C. I think I would prefer to pass a pointer to the image, as I think this would probably be the fastest solution. My search has not yielded any results thus far.

These are my custom functions in "detector.c":

```
void init_network(char *datacfg, char *cfgfile, char *weightfile, float thresh,
    float hier_thresh)
{
    options = read_data_cfg(datacfg);
    name_list = option_find_str(options, "names", "data/names.list");
    names_size = 0;
    names = get_labels_custom(name_list, &names_size); //get_labels(name_list);
    thr = thresh;
    hier_thr = hier_thresh;
    alphabet = load_alphabet();
    net = parse_network_cfg_custom(cfgfile, 1, 1); // set batch=1
    if (weightfile) {
        load_weights(&net, weightfile);
    }
    fuse_conv_batchnorm(net);
    calculate_binary_weights(net);
    if (net.layers[net.n - 1].classes != names_size) {
        printf(" Error: in the file %s number of names %d that isn't equal to classes=%d in the file %s \n",
            name_list, names_size, net.layers[net.n - 1].classes, cfgfile);
        if (net.layers[net.n - 1].classes > names_size) getchar();
    }

}
```

and prediction:

```
detection * predict_network(image im, int img_width, int img_height, int image_channels, int dont_show){
    float nms = .45;    // 0.4F
    image sized;
    sized = resize_image(im, net.w, net.h);
    layer l = net.layers[net.n - 1];

    float *X = sized.data;

    double time = get_time_point();
    network_predict(net, X);

    printf("Predicted in %lf milli-seconds.\n", ((double)get_time_point() - time) / 1000);

    int nboxes = 0;
    detection *dets = get_network_boxes(&net, im.w, im.h, thr, hier_thr, 0, 1, &nboxes, 0);
    if (nms) do_nms_sort(dets, nboxes, l.classes, nms);

    draw_detections_v3(im, dets, nboxes, thr, names, alphabet, l.classes, 0);
    save_image(im, "predictions");

    free_image(im);
    free_image(sized);

    if (!dont_show) {
        wait_until_press_key_cv();
        destroy_all_windows_cv();
    }
    return dets;

}
```

Here's my python script so far:

```
import ctypes
import time
import cv2

testlib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/aut/joax/github/AlexeyAB_darknet/libdarknet.so')

testlib.init_network(ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"fire.data"), ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"yolov3-tiny_fire.cfg"), ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"backup/yolov3-tiny_fire_best.weights"), ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"data/fire/img00063.png"), ctypes.c_float(0.25), ctypes.c_float(0.50), 0, 0, 0, "0", 0)
img = cv2.imread("data/fire/img00063.png")

height, width, channels = img.shape
testlib.predict_network(hex(id(img)), width, height, channels, 1)
testlib.release_network()
```

These aren't exactly "minimum reproducible example" but its hard to give such an example, since the darknet API is so large...

regards

Comment: Not enough information, but read about use of `.argtypes` and `.restype` in the ctypes documentation.  You don't need to `create_string_buffer` and `c_float` around every parameter if they are defined correctly.  Also what is the C definition of the `image` type?

Comment: I took a quick look at the `opencv-python` module and it looks like `img.ctypes.data` is what you should pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your answer @mark-tolonen. Your answer got me looking closer into the use of ctypes which in turn turned my attention to the fact that the darknet API actually comes with a python script that shows how use the shared library! 
The image type in darknet is a class defined as follows in python:

```
class IMAGE(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("w", c_int),
                ("h", c_int),
                ("c", c_int),
                ("data", POINTER(c_float))]
```

Defining this class in python allows for direct use as function argument with the darknet API.